Angular 12 Build Warning: Theme Class
While upgrading my Angular app to version 12, I got a warning during the build process about the .isDarkTheme class I use for toggling themes.
enter image description here
What's causing this warning, and how do I fix it?

:host-context is useful to add styles to the component but we can  lookup selectors above our defined element, so in this case, we check if the body tag has dark mode and we define styles for our component. Since it's giving a warning, we can fix it with the below method.
Suppose your component name is app-test, then we can rework the :host-context to be global-styles.css or styles.css (the file that will apply global styles to our angular project:
.isDarkTheme app-test <<add your other classes here! >> {
    // add your CSS here!
}

I am not sure if you're using SCSS or CSS, but I hope you get the concept of how to fix it.
